# How can I extend the pulse length of a gate drive transformer?

Tags: mosfet, transformer, mosfet-driver, magnetics, gate-driving

I'm designing a coilgun stage that uses a pulse transformer to switch a high side N channel mosfet.

The issue I'm having is that I can't get the firing pulse through the transformer to last longer than about 12uS. My goal is 100uS - 1mS.

Here's my minimal test circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fccwnw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The gate driver is supplied by 12V.

Things I've tried:

- Increasing/decreasing the driver side series capacitance
- Increasing/decreasing the simulated mosfet gate capacitance c1
- adding 10R series resistors on the driver and load side
- Decreasing the number of windings on the pulse transformer (this made it worse).
- Off the shelf pulse transformers, custom wound ones, different ferrite materials and diameters.

Changing the transformer does effect how long the pulse lasts, but I'm not getting anywhere near 1mS, is that even realistic? My understanding of magnetics is pretty basic so I'm basically shooting in the dark with the changes.

An example of one of the transformers I tried: 15 turns 26ga bifilliar winding on a [B64290L0038X049](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/epcos-tdk-electronics/B64290L0038X087/1830179) (N49) ferrite core.

**So essentially my question is this:** what parameters do I need to maximize to increase the pulse length this circuit can sustain?

Comment: Why use two capacitors in series like that?

Comment: To extend the drive time is effectively to lower the frequency of the signal, thus you need more primary inductance of your transformer... As you found out by reducing turns that makes it worse because you're lowering the inductance so adding turns should fix the problem.

Comment: Drew, I suspect that the Webers are going to be sheer *murderous pain* on your problem. More Webers require more core cross-section to avoid limitations in Teslas. One problem I worked on, requiring some milliseconds of pulse width, calculated out as a transformer on the rough order of "meters on a side." (Since this was supposed to be a pocket device, ... oh, well.) Seriously. Webers really get in the way of otherwise simple ideas. It's a big reason why a low-frequency AC transformer is as massive as it is. What exactly do you need to deliver? Shape, delivered energy, all that stuff?

Comment: Increase the primary inductance of your transformer.

Comment: Thanks I'll try increasing the number of turns on the transformer and report back.

Comment: Why don't use use an opto-isolated gate driver?

Comment: @Andyaka This is an alternative I'm evaluating. My current working design is opto-isolated.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely running in to core saturation. You can check for saturation by monitoring the current going through the primary of the transformer with an oscilloscope (put a 1 or 10 ohm resistor in series with the ground side of the transformer primary to monitor current). Saturation will show up as a steep rise in current. Once the transformer saturates, it will not behave as a transformer and the primary will look like a short circuit to your driver.

You can do a sanity check on the number of turns required. If you were running a 1kHz 50% duty cycle square wave through your transformer, the following equation will show you the number of turns you need to prevent saturation:
$$ N = \frac {E \, \sqrt{2} \; (1.57)}{\omega A_e \hat{B_e}} \qquad [turns] $$
Where:
\$ E \$ = rms amplitude of a sinusoid = \$ 6/\sqrt{2} \$ = 4.24V
\$ A_e \$ = effective area of core [m^2] = 7.83e-6 m^2
\$ \hat{B_e} \$ = effective flux density [T] (in this case maximum flux density) = 400mT
\$ \omega \$ = angular frequency 
1.57 = conversion factor from sine to square wave

Equation is from "Soft Ferrites" By E.C. Snelling, equation 4.16 with corrections for a square wave added in.

Plugging these numbers in to the equation shows that you need around 479 turns to avoid saturation. The tiny core area is hurting you the most.

If we turn the problem around and solve for \$ \omega \$, I would suspect you'll get a pulse of 15us before things start to saturate. Fairly close to what you're seeing.

Adding to John's post, a slick way of driving your floating gate can be found in an old International Rectifier app note: [AN-950A](https://www.mikrocontroller.net/attachment/163278/an-950.pdf). This has better reset characteristics. I have used this in the past and it works well. The diode is part of the internals of the MOSFET. The sideways MOSFET can be a low power device like a 2N7002.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fivlST.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to apply this info and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Try a circuit like the one below.  This will give you a pulsewidth that you can vary simply by changing the pulsewidth of the input.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fssUqF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks that's an interesting idea, thanks. I'd be a bit worried about how the edges of the pulse would come out though. If the mosfet got stuck in the intermediate zone for even a milisecond it would probably explode.

Comment: You can set R1 and C1 appropriately.  I use this circuit for high-side switching of brushless motors running at 600VDC and 8 amperes.